# Mapping binary search tree

Tags: c#, binary-search-tree

I have this binary search tree with Node class and I need to write mapping and filtering method for it but I have no clue how can I go through the whole tree. My every attempt to go through it skipped almost half of the tree.

```
public class BST<T> where T:IComparable<T>
{
    public class Node
    {
       public T value { get; }
       public Node left;
       public Node right;

        public Node(T element)
        {
            this.value = element;
            left = null;
            right = null;
        }
    }
    private Node root;
    private void add(T element)
    {
        if (root == null)
            root = new Node(element);
        else
        {
            add(element, root);
        }
    }
    public void add(T element, Node leaf)
    {
        if(element.CompareTo(leaf.value) > 0)
        {
            if (leaf.right == null)
                leaf.right = new Node(element);
            else
                add(element,leaf.right);
        }
        else
        {
            if (leaf.left == null)
                leaf.left = new Node(element);
            else
                add(element, leaf.left);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what values do you have in nodes?  Are they all positive?  The CompareTo() method has three results : 1)  When left object is less than right object you get a negative value 2)  When left object equals right object you get zero 3) When left object is greater than right object you get a positive results.  Your code looks like it tests for null and greater than, but not less than and zero.

Comment: all real numbers, add method works completely fine

Comment: You are only handling the case where CompareTo > 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have no clue how can I go through the whole tree

There are many ways to do that. One is to make your class iterable.

For that you can define the following method on your `Node` class:

```
    public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
    {
        if (left != null) {
            foreach (var node in left) {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
        yield return value;
        if (right != null) {
            foreach (var node in right) {
                yield return node;
            }
        }
    }
```

And delegate to it from a similar method on your `BST` class:

```
public IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
{
    if (root != null) {
        foreach (var node in root) {
            yield return node;
        }
    }
}
```

Now you can write code like this:

```
    var tree = new BST<int>();
    tree.add(4);
    tree.add(2);
    tree.add(3);
    tree.add(6);
    tree.add(5);
    
    foreach (var value in tree) {
        Console.WriteLine(value);
    }
```

> I need to write mapping and filtering method for it

It depends on what you want the result of a mapping/filtering function to be. If it is just a sequence of values, the above should be simple to adapt. If a new tree should be created with the mapped/filtered values, then feed these values back into a new tree (calling its `add`), or (in case of mapping) use the same recursive pattern of the above methods to create a new method that does not do yield, but creates a new tree while iterating the existing nodes, so the new tree has the same shape, but with mapped values.